# How to overwrite Zend_Validator error message?

Tags: php, zend-framework, validation

Just like described in title of question - I would like to have default error messages for all validators except NoRecordExists one.

In sample code below it seems that custom message overwrites all other validators messages and if for example second condition fails (Alnum) user is getting "Username already used" error message.

```
$username= new Zend_Form_Element_Text('username');
$username->setLabel('User name:')
->setRequired(TRUE)
->addValidator('NotEmpty',TRUE)
->addValidator('Alnum',TRUE)
->addValidator(new Zend_Validate_Db_NoRecordExists(array(
                    'table'=>'users',
                    'field'=>'username'
                )))
->addErrorMessages(array(
Zend_Validate_Db_NoRecordExists::ERROR_RECORD_FOUND=>'Username already used'
));
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Clearing Validation Error Messages from a Zend Form Element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5734376/clearing-validation-error-messages-from-a-zend-form-element)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I customize Zend_Form Regex error messages](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2553943/how-can-i-customise-zend-form-regex-error-messages/2554049#2554049)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try it as part of the validator call, like this:

```
$username= new Zend_Form_Element_Text('username');
$username->setLabel('User name:')
->setRequired(TRUE)
->addValidator('NotEmpty',TRUE)
->addValidator('Alnum',TRUE)
->addValidator(new Zend_Validate_Db_NoRecordExists(array(
                    'table'=>'users',
                    'field'=>'username',
                    'messages' => array(
                        Zend_Validate_Db_NoRecordExists::ERROR_RECORD_FOUND=>'Username already used')
                )));
```

this way the message is associated only with this validator.

Comment: i just used this same code, but "Username already used" not displayed. how to bring this message which record already exist